# QGIS inherent attributes

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, fields-attributes

I have a point inside a polygon. I want to copy the attributes from the point to the polygon. Is there a way to do it in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Use the **Join attributes by location** tool :)

Comment: @Joseph, sounds like an answer.

Comment: @artwork21 - Thanks but I'm fairly sure this question was asked before but can't seem to find it...